# Django REST group foreign key models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have models like below.

Menu Model

```
class Menu(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name='menu name')
```

Item Model

```
class Item(models.Model):

    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to get the menus for the shop id.

> Item.objects.filter(shop_id = 1)

How can I group my results by menu name for the shop id 1. ?

Sample.

```
{
 menu: menuname1
 items: [ {item1}, {item2}]
},
{
 menu: menuname2
 items: [ {item1}, {item2}]
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: you are asking query right?

Comment: yes. and serializer to get the json. ? Or any model structure changes for this results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your desired output with nested serializers as follows:

## models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('shop', 'menu',)

    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, related_name='items')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

## serializers

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'

class MenuSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('name','items')
```

## views

```
class MenuList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Menu.objects.filter(item__shop__id = 1)
```

I am sure you don't want everytime get shop_id = 1
so do this:

```
class MenuList(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        shop_id = int(self.kwargs['shop_id'])
        return Menu.objects.filter(item__shop__id = 1)
```

## url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url('^menus/(?P<shop_id>[0-9]+)/$', MenuList.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: We can I also split to one more model ShopMenu - whick has shop id and menu id, and make foreign key to item. What do you think about that design ? That is more suitable than current design ?

Comment: It is highly dependent to your business needs, but a piece of advice, keep it simple as possible

Comment: have to remove the unique - menu can have many items. if I remove the query returns duplicate values two time for two items for the specific shop. Menu.objects.filter(item__shop__id = 1) - return two entries. so I couln't group. ?

Comment: Have you implemented the complete answer? If done can you provide your final output of API?

Comment: I remove the unique constraint. Query need to change. the current query return duplicate values.